# View without model logic

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a view in Django Rest Framework that doesn't have any attachment to the database. The view is supposed to trigger 1 or more jobs, based on a MultipleChoiceField and some IntegerField's.

Something simple, like this:

```
class TestdataSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    count = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)
    generator = serializers.MultipleChoiceField(choices=(['a', 'a'], ['b', 'b']), write_only=True)

class Testdata(APIView):
    serializer_class = TestdataSerializer

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        return Response({'custom-list': 1234})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response({'info': 1234})
```

This kinda works (it even populates the browsable api with the correct input fields), but the MultipleChoiceField is not acting well. If I select both values in the browsable api, I am only getting the `b` (Thats if I see what `request` contains inside `post()`.).

The request payload it sends is:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryy90OuK1LRNu2zfHZ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="count"


------WebKitFormBoundaryy90OuK1LRNu2zfHZ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="generator"

a
------WebKitFormBoundaryy90OuK1LRNu2zfHZ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="generator"

b
------WebKitFormBoundaryy90OuK1LRNu2zfHZ--
```

Based on this, I would need the `MultiPartParser` parse class in DRF. And looking at the request, it is there.. But if I try to set `parser_classes` to a static list (containing `MultiPartParser` it doesnt look like the parsers are triggered. I even tried to make my own parser class, but it is never triggered.

If I look at the content of `request.data` inside my `post()` function inside the `APIView`, it container `django.http.request.QueryDict({u'count': u'', u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': u'...', u'generator': u'b'})`, when I have selected both generator a, and b.

I also tried setting `get_serializer` correct, as the `GenericAPIView` does in https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py. Still no luck.

Is there something I am forgetting here?

Comment: Are you saying that you're trying to select more than one `generator` from the DRF web front-end and it doesn't save more than one?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I clarified the question and put in some examples. Basicly, the `generator` variable will contain a string, not a list of the choiced values..

Comment: What do your models look like?

Comment: My main goal with this is to not use a model. I want a part of my API not using the DB at all.

Comment: I tried to override the `post()` function in a normal generic view, and the same thing happened. Looking at the same generic view, but in the serializers `create()` function, it worked.. So, there is something happening after the views `post()` function that fixes this. The views `post()` is called before the serializers `create()`

Comment: Oh my.. I had overlooked the answer, and had working code from the beginning, just wandered down the rabbit-hole... :( Posted my own answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `post()` that works looks like this:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = TestdataSerializer(data=request.DATA)
    serializer.is_valid()
    data = serializer.validated_data
```

Else, its all the same as in the original question. I had brainfarted and was looking for the data in the `request`, not the output from `serializer`.